# new(std::nothrow) int[n] throws an exception

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, new-operator, nothrow

```
#include <iostream>
#include <new>

int main()
{
    int n = -1;
    try
    {
        int *p = new(std::nothrow) int[n];
        if(!p)
            std::cout << "new expression returned nullptr\n";
    }
    catch(const std::bad_array_new_length& e)
    {
        std::cout << "new expression threw " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Why does this code throw an exception? It prints `new expression threw std::bad_array_new_length`.
According to the standard the new expression should return nullptr in this case.

> If the expression in a noptr-new-declarator is present, it is
>   implicitly converted to std::size_t. The expression is erroneous if:
>
> **— the expression is of non-class type and its value before converting to
>   std::size_t is less than zero;**
>
> [...]
>
> If the expression is erroneous
>   after converting to std::size_t:
>
> — if the expression is a core
>   constant expression, the program is ill-formed;
>
> — otherwise, an
>   allocation function is not called; instead
>
> **— if the allocation
>   function that would have been called has a non-throwing exception
>   specification (14.5), the value of the new-expression is the null
>   pointer value of the required result type;**
>
> — otherwise, the
>   new-expression terminates by throwing an exception of a type that
>   would match a handler (14.4) of type std::bad_array_new_length
>   (17.6.3.2).

Compiled with gcc 9.2

Comment: Filed [gcc bug 93016](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=93016).

Comment: Hm. As an aside, "after converting to std::size_t" looks erroneous. Perhaps an editing error of the standards committee?

Comment: This is [Core issue 1992](https://wg21.link/CWG1992).

Comment: @T.C. Should it throw or it's a bug? I didn't understand this from the text.

Comment: @Lassie The core issue shows throwing that exception was once a bug in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that this is a bug in libstdc++; running this code using clang and libc++ prints "new expression returned nullptr"

Comment: An error of libstdc++? Hardly, that's in the compiler proper.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I don't think so. take a look at [the libc++ implementation](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/libcxx/src/new.cpp#L112)

Comment: That shows that their nothrow op-new function properly swallows all exceptions. But one can no longer check for exceeded implementation-limit or negative input by then, that train has long ago left the station. Thus, it is irrelevant here.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't a library issue.